# Flutter - Two same components (widgets) not working separately?

Tags: flutter, class, dart

I have created a component who have a goal to handle custom autocomplete and fetch data from the server.

In view (screen) tree:

```
...widgets...
const CustomAutocomplete(
   stateToUpdate:"brokerCompanyName",
   placeholder:"Company Name",
   isRequired:true,
)
...widgets...
const CustomAutocomplete(
   stateToUpdate:"brokerName",
   placeholder:"Broker Name",
   isRequired:false,
)
...widgets...
const CustomAutocomplete(
   stateToUpdate:"brokerCompanyName",
   placeholder:"Company Name",
   isRequired:true,
)
...
```

And these two types of the same component (first and second) will work, but if I put for example third (with the same properties as the first one), won't work:

[image]

Flutter doesn't allow me to focus on the below input, my goal is to work on all of them separately.

`CustomAutocomplete` stateful widget:

```
class CustomAutocomplete extends StatefulWidget {
  final String stateToUpdate;
  final String placeholder;
  final bool isRequired;

  const CustomAutocomplete(
      {Key? key,
      required this.stateToUpdate,
      required this.placeholder,
      required this.isRequired})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<CustomAutocomplete> createState() =>
      // ignore: no_logic_in_create_state
      _CustomAutocomplete(stateToUpdate, placeholder, isRequired);
}
```

```
class _CustomAutocomplete extends State<CustomAutocomplete> {
  bool _disableLoadFromServer = false;
  bool _showAutoComplete = false;
  String _token = '';
  String _query = '';

  final String _stateToUpdate;
  final String _placeholder;
  final bool _isRequired;

  final List<UniversalModel> _listOfNames = <UniversalModel>[
    const UniversalModel(name: 'Loading data...'),
  ];

  _CustomAutocomplete(this._stateToUpdate, this._placeholder, this._isRequired);
  // functions to fetch data from server 


      return Autocomplete<UniversalModel>(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
        return _listOfNames.where((UniversalModel item) {
          return item.name
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
        }).toList();
      },
      optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
          AutocompleteOnSelected<UniversalModel> onSelected,
          Iterable<UniversalModel> options) {
        return _showAutoComplete
            ? Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Material(
                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                          maxHeight: 280,
                        ),
                        child: SizedBox(
                            width: 280,
                            height: 80,
                            child: ListView.builder(
                                padding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 0),
                                itemCount: options.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  final UniversalModel option =
                                      options.elementAt(index);
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      onSelected(option);
                                    },
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      title: Text(option.name,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: isDarkMode
                                                  ? Colors.white
                                                  : Colors.black)),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                })))))
            : const Text('');
      },
      fieldViewBuilder: (context, controller, focusNode, onEditingComplete) {
        return TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            onChanged: (text) {
              int lettersNum = text.length;
              setState(() {
                _query = text;
              });
              if (lettersNum >= 2) {
                setState(() {
                  _showAutoComplete = true;
                });
                if (lettersNum >= 3) {
                  if (!_disableLoadFromServer) {
                    fetchDataFromServer();
                  }
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    _showAutoComplete = false;
                  });
                }
              }
            },
            focusNode: focusNode,
            onEditingComplete: onEditingComplete,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            autocorrect: false,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                hintText: _placeholder,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                fillColor: isDarkMode ? const Color(0XFF212124) : Colors.white,
                filled: true),
            validator: (value) {
              if (_isRequired) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  switch (_placeholder) {
                    case 'Company Name':
                      return 'Please enter company name';
                    default:
                      return 'Please enter a value';
                  }
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    _query = value;
                  });
                }
              } else {
                setState(() {
                  _query = value;
                });
              }
              return null;
            });
      },
      onSelected: (UniversalModel selection) {
        setState(() {
          _query = selection.name;
        });
      },
      displayStringForOption: (UniversalModel option) => option.name,
    );
  }

}
```

I tried to keep the variables and content inside makes private and I have put `_` before all, but don’t work.
I understand that the problem with sharing is the data between these two components,  but I expect them to work separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure with this, but it looks like you can resolve the problem by just giving your two `customAutocomplete` items a different key by generating two `LocalKey`s for them, when you initiate them. As for now, you created two `customAutocomplete` items with the same properties, and therefore whenever you click on one of them, Flutter gives the first one in the widget tree the focus, as it calls both of them.